# Vertex Kaleidoscope shader

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, unity-game-engine, vertex-shader

I'm attempting to translate a fragment shader into a vertex shader (for mobile optimisation)

As you can see in the image below, the vertices of the center and right edge are buggy. (This is a plane with 11 x 11 vertices)

The UVs are currently mapped from the right, and wrapped around the center (with radial rotation). 
I'm guessing multiple vertices in the middle half the same value which is creating a hole?
And then the right side is cross-fading the first UV values to the final values which creates a stretched effect.

The question is how to override or fix those. (They'll probably be 2 separate problems?)

[image: kaleidoscope vertex shader]

```
uniform vec2 _Offset;
uniform float _Multiply;
varying vec4 position;
varying vec4 vert;
varying vec2 tex;
varying vec2 uv;
varying float ar;
#ifdef VERTEX  
void main()
{          
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    vec2 p = -1.0 + 2.0 * tex.xy;
    float a = atan(p.y,p.x) ;
    float r = sqrt(dot(p,p));

    uv.x = _Multiply*a/3.1416 * 2.0 + 0.1;

    float sx = sin(_Multiply*r+_Offset.x);
    float sy = _Multiply*.1*cos(_Offset.y+_Multiply*a);
    uv.y = -_Offset.x + sx + sy;

}
#endif  

#ifdef FRAGMENT

uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
void main(void)
{

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(_MainTex,uv*.5);
}
#endif                          
ENDGLSL
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Okay, essentially rewriting the shader I was able to get expected results.
And for advice to newcomers: the higher the number of vertices in your plane, the less pixel distortion will occur.

```
GLSLPROGRAM                          
#ifdef VERTEX  
varying vec2 position;
uniform float _Multiply;
uniform vec2 _Offset;
void main()
{          
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    vec2 tex = vec2(gl_MultiTexCoord0);

    vec2 p = tex.xy - 0.5;
    float r = length(p);
    float a = atan(p.y, p.x);
    float sides = _Multiply;
    float tau = 2.0 * 3.1416;
    a = mod(a, tau/sides);
    a = abs(a - tau/sides/2.0);
    position = r * vec2(cos(a), sin(a)) + 0.5  + _Offset;
}
#endif  
#ifdef FRAGMENT
varying vec2 position;
uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(_MainTex, position);
}
#endif                          
ENDGLSL
```

Comment: Using the vec2() and then .xy is redundant.  There's no point in using dependent texture coordinates, is there? Would be cool to see some readable variable names in there.  Upvote for GLSL in Unity.

Comment: hmm, what you mean about dependent texture coordinates? sorry, i'm a bit new to this. is there a better way to get normalized coordinates over the plane? thanks for the .xy part, didn't catch that.

Comment: You don't need to send position over; you can send the texture coordinate directly if all you're doing is translating it.  That counts as a dependent read: http://bit.ly/TWvCBI

Comment: "position" contains the kaleidoscope calculation. if that math was done per pixel it would require many more calculations.

Comment: You think I said the opposite of what I said; I'm saying you're doing too much per-pixel, not too little.  It's all at my link.

Comment: okay well i read the link, and moved the _Offset and 0.5 to vertex, if thats what you were referring to